# Circular view path exception in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, freemarker

I have s SpringBoot application with freemarker templates.

MvcConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder getPaswwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/user")
        .and()
            .rememberMe()
        .and()
            .logout().permitAll();
}
```

Login controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class LogInController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String greeting(Map<String, Object> model) {
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
}
```

When I ran my application and go to http://localhost:8080/login it returns an exception:

javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [login]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a recursive action~

When you try to access http://localhost:8080/login
your endpoint implementation redirects you to the same place

```
Acessing localhost:8090/login => redirect:/login
```

then try to access the same url

```
Acessing localhost:8090/login => redirect:/login
```

Comment: Try to return a ModelAndView:

Your code should be something like this:

` @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView greeting(Map<String, Object> model) {
        return new ModelAndView("login");
    }`